# Printing a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I created a function buildDictionary(text) that ultimately returns a dictionary like `{A:1, B:2, C:3}`. 
I want to create another function that will print each key in the dictionary along with its assoicated value. For example the program should print:

```
A : 1 
B : 2
C : 3
```

I tried:

```
for key, value in dictionary:
        print(key)
        print(value)
```

but the program does not print anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by **the program does not print anything**? Didn't it give you an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dictionaries iterate on keys, so the line

```
for key, value in dictionary:
```

does not do what you expect.

Instead, to use both keys and values, you need to iterate on the whole items with

```
for key, value in dictionary.items():
```

Note: the original code does not throw an error in case the key of the dictionary is a string, a tuple or any other hashable iterable with two elements, since it assigns the first element to `key` and the second to `value`

e.g.

```
>>> d={'ab':1, 'de':2}
>>> for key, value in d:
...  print(key, value)
... 
d e
a b
```

Comment: The code posted would throw an error unless all keys are two characters long. Something else is wrong.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me